# How to return boolean in Ajax call with data received from async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do data validation at `beforeSend`. This data validation should return either true or false. The data is received from asynchronous `filereader.onloadend`

If false, the function shouldn't proceed. But with code below, it actually proceed `POST`.

```
var checkValidity = function(data, callback){
    const filereader = new FileReader()
    filereader.onloadend = function(e) {
        callback(e); // I want to do validation on data received here
    }
};

$('#imageField').on('change', function(e) {
    var formData = new FormData();

    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function() {
            var data = formData.getAll('inputField');
            checkValidity(data, function(e){
                // if console.log(e) here, actually return expected value

                // I'm trying to return false/true here
                e ? return true : return false
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why cant you call the validation function just before ajax call? And based on that you can opt to post the data.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. I just thought it's 'cleaner' and readable by putting the validation at `beforeSend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the ajax only after successful validation

```
var checkValidity = function(data, callback) {
  const filereader = new FileReader()
  filereader.onloadend = function(e) {
    callback(e); // I want to do validation on data received here
  }
};

$('#imageField').on('change', function(e) {
  var formData = new FormData();

  var data = formData.getAll('inputField');
  checkValidity(data, function(e) {
    e ?
      return true: return false
  });


  If(conditionToCheckIfValid) {
    $.ajax({
      data: formData,
      type: 'POST',
      // rest of the code 
    });
  }
});
```